# Mockito ArgumentCaptor: How to capture Class and Object

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I've been trying to capture some types and I can't find a clean solution. I got this:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<T extends DTO> targetMapperCaptor;
```

I'm using this Captor against a mapper using 2 types of params; a instance or a clazz.

As it's declared is only capturing those object that extends DTO, for capturing the classes:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Class> targetMapperCaptor;
```

Giving an example, having this code in the implementation:

```
mock.map(MyObject.class);
mock.map(new MyObject());
```

And having this in the test:

```
when(mock, times(2)).map(targetMapperCaptor.capture());
```

Will always throw an TooLittleActualInvocations (wanted 2 but got 1). If we remove the times(2), inside the targetMapperCaptor.getAllValues() there is only the value that matchs the type.

There is any way of declaring the ArgumentCaptor for capturing any param?

I've also unsuccessfully tried:

```
private ArgumentCaptor<?> targetMapperCaptor;
private ArgumentCaptor targetMapperCaptor;
```

Comment: I would argue that your approach have having a general captor is wrong. Use two specific captors and check that the corresponding `map` overload has been called exactly one time (not two).

Comment: Sounds viable, I wanted to make it in just one instance of ArgumentCaptor, using this way I have to perform more verifications, but it's more exhaustive using your proposal, it must verify if It's calling the Class mehtod or the Instance method.

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Tom

Comment: What do you mean with "it must verify if It's calling the Class mehtod or the Instance method.". What is "it"? When you mean your mocking framework, then 'yes', but that doesn't matter much. It is more important that your tests are clear and understandable. Having two specific captors with clear types make your test also clearer to read and to understand.

Comment: Completely agree. Sorry, "It" is the test itself. I wanted to say that the test it's more exhaustive using the way you propose. Verifying one call has been made to the class method and one call has been made to the instance method.

Comment: If that solved your question, then feel free to post an answer explaining how you solved it :). You then can accept that post.